# Can I do an RFC2544 test with a JDSU SmartClass Ethernet and a C1921?

Tags: cisco, throughput, metro-ethernet, rfc

I need to do RFC2544 tests of about 70 links, in different locations, before July ends and I only have about 11 JDSUs, so for some of this tests I won't have 2 JDSU available where I need them.

Is it possible to emulate the behaviour of the JDSU working as a loopback with a Cisco router and do the test with only one JDSU?

I could use C1921 or get a couple of 2900/3900 series if required.